What is the correct syntax for an sshtunnel from Python?
I am trying to open an ssh tunnel from Python, but I cannot seem to get the syntax correct.
Essentially, I want to do the following, except from within Python:
ssh -i /path/to/my/private.ca.key -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 user@ourserver.com

When I enter that line directly in bash it works fine.
My python code looks like this:
import logging
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

# Path to the private key file
private_key_path = '/path/to/my/private.ca.key'

# Establish SSH tunnel
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    'ourserver.com',
    ssh_username='user',
    ssh_pkey = private_key_path,
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306),
    local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306)
)

server.start()

This is my output:
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0x79d3c9d0
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_3.4.1
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u3
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_9.2p1)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:=== Key exchange possibilities ===
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com, curve25519-sha256, curve25519-sha256@libssh.org, ecdh-sha2-nistp256, ecdh-sha2-nistp384, ecdh-sha2-nistp521, diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256, diffie-hellman-group16-sha512, diffie-hellman-group18-sha512, diffie-hellman-group14-sha256, kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server key: rsa-sha2-512, rsa-sha2-256, rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com, rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client encrypt: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com, aes128-ctr, aes192-ctr, aes256-ctr, aes128-gcm@openssh.com, aes256-gcm@openssh.com
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server encrypt: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com, aes128-ctr, aes192-ctr, aes256-ctr, aes128-gcm@openssh.com, aes256-gcm@openssh.com
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client mac: umac-64-etm@openssh.com, umac-128-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com, umac-64@openssh.com, umac-128@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-256, hmac-sha2-512, hmac-sha1
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server mac: umac-64-etm@openssh.com, umac-128-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com, umac-64@openssh.com, umac-128@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-256, hmac-sha2-512, hmac-sha1
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client compress: none, zlib@openssh.com
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server compress: none, zlib@openssh.com
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client lang: <none>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server lang: <none>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex follows: False
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:=== Key exchange agreements ===
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Strict kex mode: True
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:HostKey: rsa-sha2-512
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Cipher: aes128-ctr
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:MAC: hmac-sha2-256
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Compression: none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:=== End of kex handshake ===
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Resetting outbound seqno after NEWKEYS due to strict mode
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex engine KexCurve25519 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Resetting inbound seqno after NEWKEYS due to strict mode
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Got EXT_INFO: {'server-sig-algs': b'ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-dss,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512', 'publickey-hostbound@openssh.com': b'0'}
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Attempting public-key auth...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) failed.
2024-08-26 16:12:00,129| ERROR   | Could not open connection to gateway
ERROR:sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder:Could not open connection to gateway
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[filename].py", line 18, in <module>
    server.start()
  File ".../site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 1331, in start
    self._raise(BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError,
  File ".../site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 1174, in _raise
    raise exception(reason)
sshtunnel.BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError: Could not establish session to SSH gateway

My private key uses the 'ssh-rsa' algorithm, and the server seems to confirm that it understands that algorithm during negotiation according to the following line:
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Got EXT_INFO: {'server-sig-algs': b'ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-dss,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512', 'publickey-hostbound@openssh.com': b'0'}


I don't think this error has anything to do with the tunnel. The error is "INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) failed." So there was an authentication problem. Can you make other SSH connections with Paramiko?

Yes, obviously it is an authentication problem. But since the key works with the ssh command as shown there must be something about the way I call it that could improve the situation.

I don't know offhand if paramiko uses all the settings from ~/.ssh, so maybe it's using a different authentication than the ssh command.

My private key uses the 'ssh-rsa' Sounds like the clue. Please post verbose logs from ssh command to compare. You may be hitting this: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/2143 - try downgrading to paramico < 2.9.

I did eventually get it working.
I tried a basic paramiko connection with the following code:
import paramiko

ssh_hostname = 'ourserver.com'
ssh_username = 'user'
private_key_path = '/path/to/private.rsa.key'

key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(private_key_path)
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname, port, username=username, pkey=key, look_for_keys=False, compress=True)

Note #1
My original keyfile began with the line:
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----

The paramiko library didn't like that key, but it did like it after I converted it with the following command (which will overwrite your keyfile)
ssh-keygen -p -m PEM -f /path/to/private.rsa.key
Now my key begins with the following line which paramiko is happier with.
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

The underlying key is the same, but it's now encrypted differently.
Note #2
My key is signed with a certificate which means that my public key did not need to be in the 'authorized_keys' file on the remote host for cmdline ssh to work. Paramiko didn't seem to be picking up the certificate, though. There may be a way to fix this, but my quick workaround was to put my public key in the 'authorized_keys' file on that host.
If I figure out how to configure paramiko to recognize the certificate, which would be a better solution, I may update this post.
Also
Downgrading paramiko didn't help. My solution worked with pip install paramiko==3.4.1.
